# Does my internet split itself between virtual machines?

Tags: virtualbox, internet

I have a 100mbps network card. And I have 2 virtual machines - Ubuntu and Windows xp sp3 running under VirtualBox.

And my machine that is not virtual is Windows 7. Do they get equal priority?  (33,3% each)
Or does my hist machine get more priority?  Or is it on first come first serve basis?

Answer (score 1):

Since in all likelihood you are using a virtual bridge to split the connection between the VMs and host, the bandwidth would be divided roughly equally, if all of them are using it.

If however there is any free bandwidth, any of the OS'es can use it

example:

100mbps connection, each OS is saturating the  connection, the bandwidth will be divided roughly equally

100mbps connection, 1 OS is using 50 mbps, the 2nd is using 20mbps then its not an issue

Answer (score 0):

In your computer you have installed windows 7 so it will get the highest priority and the the virtual machine will be the next. When windows 7 is using the internet and your two virtual OS are ON at that time the windows 7 will get little bit more speed and the internet speed will be less for the virtual OS. In the virtual OS the speed will be further divided.

Answer (score 0):

This all depends on your Gateway (for Internet), Router (for LAN) or network cards (for direct crossover). In general, your virtual Machine gets the same priority as every other machine connected to the network, however, most low-end consumer routers don't really distribute the available bandwidth equally, it's as simple as "first packet to arrive gets served first".

If you want to restrict your VMs, some Hypervisors/VM Hosts like VMWare allow you to restrict the network bandwidth. **Note that this limitation will also apply for local transfers**!